# Binding XML data to Model in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I'm looking to bind XML to Model in C# MVC app.

XML:

```
<people>  
    <person>
        <name>Mr Brown</name>
        <age>40</age>
        <hobby>
            <title>Eating</title>
            <description>eats a lot</description>
        </hobby>
        <hobby>
            <title>Sleeping</title>
            <description>sleeps a lot</description>
        </hobby>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Mr White</name>
        <age>40</age>
        <hobby>
            <title>Skiing</title>
            <description>more details on this</description>
        </hobby>
        <hobby>
            <title>Football</title>
            <description>watches football</description>
        </hobby>
    </person>
</people>
```

Model:

```
public class People
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public IList<Hobbies> Hobby {get; set; }
}
public class Hobbies
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Broken Binding:

```
var person = from a in xml.Descendants("person")
select new People 
{
    Name = a.Element("name").Value,
    Age = a.Element("age").Value,
    Hobby = *WHAT GOES HERE?*
}
```

I'n new to C# and looking for the best way to bind the data from the XML to the `person` var. Which I'll later loop over and output in an HTML table.

Any help would be great.

Comment: can you change `xml` structure? if yes just put your `<hobby>` `tag` to container i.e `<hobbies>` and then deserialize it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
var person = from a in xml.Descendants("person")
              select new People 
              {
                Name = a.Element("name").Value,
                Age = a.Element("age").Value,
                Hobby = a.Descendants("hobby")
                          .Select(x=> new Hobbies
                                       {
                                         Title =x.Element("title").Value,
                                         Description = x.Element("description").Value
                                       }).ToList()
               };
```

### WORKING FIDDLE:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uKdd5

Answer (score 1):

I would use XmlSerializer to load from Xml and to save to xml.
You can derive People from this class for example (SerializeManagement)  :

```
public class SerializeManagement<T>
{
    public static T ReadFromXML(string iPath)
     {
        T val = default(T);
        try
        {
            // load from XML
            using (var sw = new StreamReader(iPath, Encoding.Default))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                val = (T)ser.Deserialize(sw);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem reading from xml data file.");
        }

        return val;
    }

    public void SaveToXML(string iPath)

    {
        try
        {
            //TODO => using
            var sw = new StreamWriter(iPath, false, Encoding.Default);
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(sw, this);
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem saving to xml data file.");
        }
    }
}
```

If you encounter problems, this could be because of your model definition or xml structure :

Then you can :

**1)** Generate c# class from the xml using xsd utility;

**2)** Generate XML from existing class using SaveToXML. That way you are sure the XML structure is compliant with your model.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want standard XML deserialization. Some good answers on the best way to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)